# Is it possible to auto login in a web application using the username and password entered at the startup of windows?

Tags: .net

I am new to .net and in learning phase only.I want to make an application which automatically grabs the username and password entered at the time of start up of windows and login the user in that application with that username and password.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged this .NET,

Yes. It is called Windows Authentication.

It requires IE on the client side and an IIS server. It only suitable for IntraNet.

Comment: can you point towards some good document or related question where i can detailed answer. and what area i should focus on to study about this.

Comment: @James, Yes, type "Windows Authentication" in a search engine.

Comment: I believe that Chrome and Firefox on windows are also able to authenticate with windows auth as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please tell me is it possible to do the above using JAVA

Comment: @James: I don't know about Java but I very much doubt it. But what kind of Java app? JSP?

Comment: @ Henk if Java i would use JSP only

Answer (score 0):

Nobody's gonna give you any answer here, everybody over here has got the habit of posting half and incorrect answers and redirecting to other links.

The answer to your question is:

```
Use-> string user = Page.User.Identity.Name;
```

Try this for getting the username.

Also in IIS go to the properties of the hosted virtual folder,
go to Directory Security tab and click edit of "Anonymous access and authentication control",
in that uncheck all the check boxes and check only "integrated windows authentication".

Also, make sure that the pc on which you are testing and the server on which the web application is hosted are on the same domain. Else you won't get the username of pc and instead will get the server name.